# Query map value with SpringData and QueryDSL-JPA

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I got the following data structure

```
@Entity
public class Publication {
   private Map<Integer, Author> authors;
   // more stuff
}

@Entity
public class Author {
   private String name;
   // more stuff
}
```

I'm looking for a query dsl predicate which gives my all publication where any Author.name contains a certain String e.g. "Hans"

I tried:

```
QPublication publication = QPublication.publication;
QAuthor author = QAuthor.author;
publication.authors.containsValue(JPAExpressions.selectFrom(author).where(author.lastName.containsIgnoreCase("Hans")));
```

But this complains if there is more than one author containing "Hans" in the name. Is there somenting like `publication.authors.anyValue().name.equalsIgrnoreCase("Hans")` like there is for a Set?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with a join and a custom repository implementation:

```
public class PublicationRepositoryImpl extends QueryDslRepositorySupport 
   implements PublicationRepositoryCustom {

@Override
public Page<Publication> findByAnyAuthorName(String name, PageRequest pageRequest) {
   QPublication publication = QPublication.publication;
   JPQLQuery<Publication> query = from(publication);
   QAuthor author = QAuthor.author;
   query.join(publication.authors, author);
   query.where(author.name.containsIgnoreCase(name);
   JPQLQuery<Publication> pagedQuery = getQuerydsl()
      .applyPagination(pageRequest, query);

   return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(pagedQuery.fetch(), pageRequest,
    () -> query.fetchCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the
[BooleanBuilder](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.7/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/BooleanBuilder.html)

in your Repository - try this

```
QPublication publication = QPublication.publication;
QAuthor author = QAuthor.author;
BooleanBuilder where= new BooleanBuilder();
where.and(publication.author.name.containsIgnoreCase(textToSearch));

//pass the where condition to the desired Repo method
repo.findAll(where);
```

Comment: Since `Publication.authors` is a map, there is no `publication.author` The `BoolenBuilder` is not needed if you only have one condition